# How to implement Thread for specific method in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

i have this following method which i want to call with thread because i want to execute this method independently in background.. So, can anyone tell me how can i do this?

I have following function in `EmailNotification` class

```java
public class EmailNotification {
public void SendEmailNotificationForCampaign(String[] pCamp_ids,
            List<String> pReciepientAddresses, campaign pCampObj,
            ThemeDisplay pThemeDisplay, OPERATION pOperation,
            List<String> pSmptpObjList, String pLogoPath) {

        GenerateCampaignEmailMessage(pCamp_ids, pReciepientAddresses, pCampObj,
                pThemeDisplay, pOperation, pSmptpObjList, pLogoPath);
    }
}
```

Following is the code from RestaurantPortlet Class in which am calling above method

```java
EmailNotification emailnotifyObj = new EmailNotification();
                            emailnotifyObj.SendEmailNotificationForAdvertise(sAdvIds,
                                    RecipientAdress, updatedAdv, pthemeDisplay,
                                    OPERATION.AD_DELETE, ReadSmtpDataForMailNotification(), pthemeDisplay.getPortalURL()+"/eMenuAdvertise-portlet/img/eMenuLogo.png");
```

So how can i implement SendEmailNotificationForCampaign Method with the thread.?can anyone let me guide?i am new to Thread Concept .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and probably best idea would be to make a static queue for all pending emails. All producer threads would add the mail to the queue and the other thread would process and send these emails.

Look at the [producer/consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Example_in_Java) problem in wiki, it will give you a pretty good idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        //your code here, for example:
        EmailNotification emailnotifyObj = new EmailNotification();
        emailnotifyObj.SendEmailNotificationForAdvertise(sAdvIds,
                                RecipientAdress, updatedAdv, pthemeDisplay,
                                OPERATION.AD_DELETE, ReadSmtpDataForMailNotification(), pthemeDisplay.getPortalURL()+"/eMenuAdvertise-portlet/img/eMenuLogo.png");
    }
}

new Thread(task).start();
```

Note that:

- this will or will not work as expected depending on what `GenerateCampaignEmailMessage` does. In particular, if it accesses variables that you also access from the rest of your code, you would need to synchronize those accesses properly.
- if you send many emails, you don't want to create one thread per email and should use a Thread Pool instead.

Comment: can u please explain more deeply about your Note?

Comment: @BhavikKama Many problems can arise if you have a shared variable across threads (let's call it `a`). For example if you write to that variable in Thread T0: `a = 1234;` and later on read the variable in Thread T1: `b = a;`, you don't have any guarantee that b will be 1234 without proper synchronization.

Comment: @BhavikKama If your method only uses the parameters that are passed to it, and assuming that the parameters are not modified by other threads, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to me Suggestion is use other than thread like JMS to send message using java mail.

If you wish to do Thread to send mail also you can use the TimerTask for it.

It you want only Thread not other options to make single method Synchronizable.

**[CHECK THE LINK](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html)**

```
public synchoronized setCount(int count){
   this.count = count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a service that contains an ExecutorService inside, and passes the email sending tasks into the executor sevice. Vaguely:

```
class EmailService {
   private ExecutorService executor;

   public sendMail(arguments) {
      executor.submit(new Runnable() {
         //send mail with given parameters
      }
   }
}
```

This way you will have handles on your threads running in the background, and they can be shutdown if needed (e.g. running too long). Simply starting new threads may kill your app if too many threads started simultaneously.

Have a look at the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)